# Is $\sum_{n=2}^∞ (\cos1)^n$ convergent and find its sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Now, I'm going to be clear on this one before anyone complains. Yes, this was part of the lectures, I just wanna know if I've solved this one correctly.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\cos1)^n$$

So, its a geometric series, where $\cos1$ is just a number raised to $n$ and $|r|<1$, so its convergent.

The sum:

$$S=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{(\cos1)^2}{1-\cos1}=0.135$$

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks

Comment: That's fine, just a small typo to fix $$S=\frac{1}{1-r}-1-r=\frac{1-(1-r^2)}{1-r}=\frac{r^2}{1-r}=\frac{(\cos1)^2}{1-\cos1}$$

Comment: @user could you please explain what you wrote above? Isn't the sum of geometric series just $S=\frac{a}{1-r}$? I got some points taken off in this particular example, so im trying to be careful.

Comment: @GreasyLlama Let me know if things are clear now. Are you implicitely assuming $a=r^2$ or you just made a typo?

Comment: The notations $a$ and $r$ ate not standard notations, please explain what they are. Also, add a step to explain why you have $a=r^2$.

Comment: @LL3.14 Indeed the answer is correct of course but the solution process is not clear at all. I also think an explanation is required for the last expression.

Comment: @user well, from what I know, $r$ is whatever is inside the parentheses, so $\cos1 $ and $a$ is the first term, so $(\cos 1)^2$. Am I correct here?

Comment: @GreasyLlama It would be useful see all your work to check if your solution process is fine. In my answer you can find two different ways to proceed. Have you adopted one of them? Or have you followed another way?

Comment: @user I do understand the second method you used. I just followed this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYxzq_O18Mg&ab_channel=patrickJMT

Comment: @GreasyLlama Ah ok now it is clear! That's fine but it is just a recipe non completely explained in the linked video. You can of course follow the explanation given in the second method to understand what is going on. I suggest in any case to do not adopt $a$ in the expression, it doesn't seem correct. You can just use $r^2$, which is the first term for the series. As a suggestion, try to understand better the process, insted to apply blindily formulas.

Comment: Apply Geometric series Test

Comment: Perhaps mention explicitly the reason it works:  $|\cos 1| < 1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Result is fine but there is a small typo which seems an issue not totally clear to you.

Recall that

$$S_0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ar^n=\frac a{1-r}$$

and in this case $a=1$ and starting from $n=2$ we obtain

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n -1-r=\frac{1}{1-r}-1-r=\frac{1-(1-r^2)}{1-r}=\frac{r^2}{1-r}=\frac{(\cos1)^2}{1-\cos1}$$

---

**Edit**

As an alternative interpretation, as indicated by ArticChar in the comments, we also have

$$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r^n=r^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} r^{n-2}=r^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^{k}=r^2S_0=\frac{r^2}{1-r}$$

which is another clever way to obtain the result.

---

**Edit 2**

Following the previous example, more in general we have

$$S=\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} r^n=r^{n_0}\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} r^{n-n_0}=r^{n_0}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^{k}=r^{n_0}S_0=\frac{r^{n_0}}{1-r}$$

which explain the recipe given i the video you are referring to, that is to put in the numerator the first value for the series which in your case is indeed $r^2=\cos^2(1)$.

Comment: Look like they are using $a = r^2$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: $(r^2) 1 + (r^2) r + (r^2) r^2 + \cdots$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Ah ok that's fine, I add also this interpretation. It could also be the case. Thanks

Comment: Then at least don't say that they have a typo...

Comment: @ArcticChar My first impression was that the asker had a typo there: $$S=\frac{a}{1-r}=\frac{(\cos1)^2}{1-\cos1}=0.135$$ It seems indeed not much consistent with what was included in the question. Then, after my first comment, asker required an explanation. For that reason I've added an answer explaining my point. Your way to see things can also be a good explanation. Maybe the asker will clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is just a generalized version of the geometric series. 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k $$ 
For $ x \ge 1 $ the succession $ a_n \rightarrow + \infty $ so it doesn't go to 0, that follows it diverges. 

For $0<x<1$ we prove by induction that
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ 
For $n=0, \space 1= \frac{1-x}{1-x} \quad p_0$ is true 
Suppose n true for $p_n$, we need to control $p_{n+1}$
$S_n + x^{n+1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}+x^{n+1}=\frac{1-x^{n+2}}{1-x}$ so $p_{n+1}$ is true 

For $x \le 1$ the sum doesn't converge or diverge 

Said that, being $\cos(1)=0.504...<1$ we can say it converge to the result you have found.